# Rails: How to work with serialize attributes and Sorbet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorbet

I can't find any examples of how to deal with attributes that are `serialized` columns.

```
class MyClass < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :related_pages, Array
end
```

In this case, it is an `Array` of `String` (eg `T::Array[String]`).

The only solution I have found is to cast it: `T.cast(related_pages, T::Array[String])`

Is this the best solution?

Comment: The best solution is to not use serialized attributes in the first place. If you really want to violate 1NF (hint: you don't) then databases have native JSON/Array columns anyways nowadays. But do youself a favor and use a join table.

Comment: And what's the second-best solution? Rewriting code and database of 10s of millions of rows is probably not going to happen.

Comment: Native JSON columns. Serialized array columns is basically just a comma separated string.

Comment: I meant a solution in code that doesn't change the database. Everything works fine, it's just Sorbet that is the issue. I will stick with my `T.cast` solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a good way to *automatically* get what you want right now. I'd say to use Tapioca, but it looks like it generates untyped getters and setters for `serialize` calls, which won't help you. If you feel confident in Tapioca, I suppose you could write your own DSL compiler, but that's its own can of worms.

That said, there is a way to get around this manually that doesn't involve `T.cast`: you can write your own `.rbi` files. It has some problems (e.g. you have to keep them in sync yourself, and you're basically asserting to the type checker that you know what you're doing) but it's a possibility!

For yours, I think it'd look like this (I haven't run this; it's just for illustration):

```rb
# typed: strict

class MyClass
  extend T::Sig

  sig { returns(T::Array[String]) }
  def related_pages; end

  sig { params(value: T::Array[String]).returns(T::Array[String]) }
  def related_pages=(value); end

  # whatever other helper methods you need like `related_pages_before_last_save` etc
end
```